# Rx Observable share() with skip() usage issue

Tags: rx-java

I have a code, where the shared observable is used. One of the shared instances there uses extra skip and debounce operators. The problem is that sometimes the action for the instance where skip and debounce is used is not called

```
Observable<Integer> beginChanged = RxBindingUtils
        .valueChanged(begin)
        .doOnEach(value -> Timber.d("Begin value changed: " + value.getValue()))
        .share();

monitor(
        beginChanged
                .map(minutes -> minutesToTime(minutes))
                .subscribe(beginTime.asAction()));
monitor(
        beginChanged
                .map(minutes -> minutes / interval)
                .subscribe(rangeBegin.asAction()));
monitor(
        beginChanged 
                .skip(1)// skip initial value emitted automatically right after the
                        // subsription
                .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)// such as range bar may change the
                        // value very quickly use the
                        // debounce function for the timeout
                        // based processing
                .doOnEach(value -> Timber.d("Begin value changed 2: " + value.getValue()))
                .subscribe(mSchedulerRangeBegin.asAction()));
```

If i replace the last occurrence of the beginChanges with the new observable it works as expected

```
monitor(
        RxBindingUtils
                .valueChanged(begin) // can't use shared observable because of unexpected behaviour with skip call
                .skip(1)// skip initial value emitted automatically right after the
                        // subsription
                .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)// such as range bar may change the
                        // value very quickly use the
                        // debounce function for the timeout
                        // based processing
                .doOnEach(value -> Timber.d("Begin value changed 2: " + value.getValue()))
                .subscribe(mSchedulerRangeBegin.asAction()));
```

Are there any restrictions which don't allow to use skip and debounce on shared observables?

Comment: Could you clarify what behaviour you're seeing vs what you're expecting?

Comment: @AdamS with the help of rx developers i've solved the issue. share was replaced with the publish-connect sequence https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3578

Comment: If you could post the answer here too that'd be helpful for the next person who encounters this! :)

Comment: @AdamS ok, done that

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer from the akarnokd taken from [github](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3578)

> Okay, I see what's wrong. The begin emits its current value on
>   subscription which is triggered by the first Subscriber to share() and
>   since all is synchronous, the subsequent subscribers don't get
>   anything at that point because they are not yet subscribed. When the
>   first event arrives, it gets skipped and only the second event is then
>   processed. If you replace share with replay().refCount(), the test
>   passes.

In my case the issue was solved by replacing `share()` with the `publish()` and after all the subscribers subscribed `connect()` call.